# Defining Relationships for common junction table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 3 tables - registers, items and item_kits

And a junction table - registers_items (Structure - register_id, item_id, item_kit_id, OTHER EXTRA COLUMNS) (item_id and item_kit_id refer to their respective table and can be NULL)

As I have common extra columns for both of them, I decided to keep a common junction table. Relationships defined in RegistersTable.php are :

```
$this->belongsToMany('ItemKits', [
    'foreignKey' => 'register_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'item_kit_id',
    'joinTable' => 'registers_items'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('Items', [
    'foreignKey' => 'register_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'item_id',
    'joinTable' => 'registers_items'
]);
```

From the form on Registers page, I pass this post data :

```
[items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [_joinData] => Array
                    (
                        // All the extra columns data
                    )
            )
            // ....
    )
[item_kits] => Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [_joinData] => Array
                    (
                        // All the extra columns data
                    )
            )
            // ....
    )
```

It saved only the items in the registers_items table. I expect both of them to be saved. What am I missing?

Upon debugging more, I found that there is no issue with relationships definitions. The problem is that I am using single table for 2 junctions. So, 2nd one overrides the first one and the data of first relationship doesn't get saved in table. I even tried 'through' option but same result. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just drop the idea of having a common join table for both associations, that goes against database normalization and as you have already discovered, it makes things more complicated when dealing with the application code.